# can't create actionlib client

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, I'm kinda new to this as well as c++ so plz bear with me.
I'm trying to get a simple_action_client working in roscpp, but cant seem get the template constructor to accept my action. Here's an example:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <control_msgs/JointTrajectoryAction.h>
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>

typedef  actionlib::SimpleActionClient<control_msgs::JointTrajectoryAction> Client_t;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "move_joints", ros::init_options::AnonymousName);
  ros::NodeHandle nh
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();
  Client_t client;
[  ....   ]
```

It's giving me a "no matching function" error for the client typdef. Looking at the api documentation does not tell me much. I'm confused as an equivalent python script such as the following works just fine:

```
import rospy
import actionlib
from control_msgs.msg import *
from trajectory_msgs.msg import *

def main():
   rospy.init_node("move_joints", anonymous=True, disable_signals=True)
   client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('follow_joint_trajectory',FollowJointTrajectoryAction)
  [...]
```

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81651/can%27t-create--actionlib-client/) by [octavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5698/octavian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to specify the action.
Do this (if you want to call the action 'follow_joint_trajectory'):

```
Client_t client("follow_joint_trajectory", true);
```

[This actionlib tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionClient) is very easy and well written.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [octavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5698/octavian/) on 2013-09-21**:
Thanks for the response. That was pretty silly of me to overlook that. I'll be more scrupulous next time :)

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-09-21**:
Your welcome. If your problem is solved, please mark the answer as correct.

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2014-04-26**:
Hi BennyRe, I don't know if you can help me to solve this problem: http://answers.ros.org/question/157696/actionlib-client-question/. Thanks for your help!